# Renaming files in a loop - permission denied or the object invoked has disconnected from its clients errors

Tags: vbscript, rename

I am trying to include a renaming function to a loop which opens Word files and looks for tracked changes - if there are Tracked changes, I want to rename the file to get a _tracked_changes_ prefix.

However, I encounter a problem - I get a permission denied error, I am assuming because the file is open when I am trying to rename it. However, when I include the objFile.close function, the "object invoked has disconnected from its clients". I don't know how can I keep the reference of the objFile variable to the file I am processing and bypass the "permission denied" problem.

The code is:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    app.Visible = false
    app.DisplayAlerts = true


For Each objFile In fso.GetFolder(".").Files
    If Lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "docx" Then
    <<<subprocedure that checks for tracked changes>>>
    set objFile = app.Documents.Open(objFile.Path)
    objFile.Name = "_tracked_changes_" & objfile.name
    'Call check_tc

End If
```

Next

This naturally works fine if I don't have the set objFile = app.Documents.Open(objFile.Path) element, but I have to open the file to see if it has tracked changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the `set objFile = app.Documents.Open(objFile.Path)` to something else besides `objFile`, as this is reusing the first `objFile` and that'd be why you're getting the disconnected error.

Then you should be able to close it.
So
`set objWord = app.Documents.Open(objFile.Path)`
`objWord.close`
Then
`objFile.Name = "_tracked_changes_" & objfile.name`

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
That works indeed - I would have press vote up, but my reputation's too low ;-)